# only one JLabel displaying at a time (Java Swing)

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, layout-manager, border-layout

I created one JLabel as a heading and customised it, which displayed with no issue. The problem came when I attempted to create a second JLabel, as only the second JLabel would display. When I created a third one, only that would display but not the first and second.

Basically, only the latest JLabel is being displayed. How can I have multiple JLabel's displayed simultaneously.

Here is my code.

```
public class MainForm extends JFrame {

EmployeeDAO dao = new EmployeeDAO();
private static JLabel label, name;


MainForm()
{
    super("Employee Database");
    GUI();  
}

private void GUI()
{
    JLabel label = new JLabel("Enter Employee Information");
    label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);
    label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
    label.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 20));
    label.setForeground(Color.red);
    add(label);

    JLabel name = new JLabel("Name: ");
    add(name);
    }
}
```

Comment: `JFrame` uses a `BorderLayout` by default, which displays only a single component at any of the 5 positions it has available (center been the default), try changing the layout, start by having a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)

Comment: You might want to read [How to Use Labels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html).

Answer (score 0):

Usually, when you want to add more than one component to a container (as you're doing with the JLabels in the JFrame) you must decide which layout manager do you want to use so that components are displayed in the positions you want.

You should probably take a look at the tutorials related to [laying out components in containers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

You will need to select a [Layout Manager](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html), and call `setLayout` accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.setBounds` for each element you are adding to your scene, or use another layout such as grid layout to position your UI elements. The problem stems from when you add a new element, it goes on top of previous one.